# read a list of IP address and execute commands depending on OS type

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am working on a script to read from a file having multiple IP addresses, login to each system (no ssh keys involved and manually entering password), execute a command depending on OS type and print the result.

Here is how IPs are defined in the hosts.txt file

```
#~] cat hosts.txt

10.6.3.131

10.6.3.132

10.6.3.11

10.6.3.12
```

When I execute the below script, the following errors are shown. Also, The script does not prompt for 2nd and rest IPs in the list. What could be causing this?

```
# ./hq-test1.sh

root@10.6.3.131's password:

awk: cmd. line:1: NR==1{print

awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string

bash: line 2: [: !=: unary operator expected

10.6.3.131 == PASS
```

This is the script used in test :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read HOST; do

  if ssh root@$HOST '

      STATUS=`awk 'NR==1{print $1}' /etc/*release`

      [ $STATUS != "CentOS" ]

   '; then

       echo "$HOST == FAIL"

  else

       echo "$HOST == PASS"

  fi

done < hosts.txt
```

Comment: your quoting doesn't seem to be correct. Escape the single quotes around your awk script. Might help

Comment: #!/bin/bash
while read HOST; do

 if  ssh root@$HOST
      STATUS=`awk 'NR==1{print $1}' /etc/*release`
    [ "$STATUS" != "CentOS" ]
    then
       echo "$HOST == FAIL"
  else
       echo "$HOST == PASS"
  fi
done < hosts.txt

Answer (score 2):

Your script isn't closing `stdin` while running the `ssh` command so only the first host of the list is processed.

I also simplified the test, as `awk` is able to check the OS name and the temporary variable is unnecessary.

```
while read host; do
  if ssh -n root@$host '[ "$(awk "/CentOS/{print}" /etc/*release)" ] '
  then
       echo "$host == PASS"
  else
       echo "$host == FAIL"
  fi
done < hosts.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. As I already wrote, it's just a quoting issue.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo localhost | while read HOST; do

  if ssh root@$HOST '

      STATUS=`awk "NR==1{print \$1}" /etc/*release`

      [ $STATUS != "CentOS" ]

   '; then

       echo "$HOST == FAIL"

  else

       echo "$HOST == PASS"

  fi

done
```

Comment: Tried and worked except the following bash: line 4: [: too many arguments..                                               
Now the issue is that, the script stops after executing on 1st IP in hosts.txt file.. What changes are required so that script continues to read the txt file and execute on all IP address listed?

Comment: OK, the `while read HOST` makes problems. change it to `for HOST in \`cat hosts.txt\`; then ...`